# Error after installing JA multilingual Joomla extension

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Before I have installed JA Mulltilingual extension for joomla, I had english and serbian (default) language. Then I tried this extension, and my web pages display the same errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But, if i choose english as default, there is no errors. 
Does anyone know what is the problem?
I can upload *languagefilter.php*.
I have tried to copy this file from my backup, but still nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have find out that this extension has enabled my **language filter** plugin. I have just turned it off, and everything is ok now.